# Task scheduler with dependencies

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, graph, scheduled-tasks

I have need for a task scheduler determined by a directed graph. The tasks are held in a `std::vector<task_type>`, while the dependency graph is held in a `adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS>` (`bidirectionalS` so that I have access to the `in_degree()` function). A single dispatch will start the tasks. Are there obvious improvements here?

To set up a task dependency graph as below, use the driver provided.

[image]

**scheduler_driver.hpp:**

```
#ifndef __SCHEDULER_DRIVER_HPP__
#define __SCHEDULER_DRIVER_HPP__

#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

#include "scheduler.h"

#endif
```

**scheduler_driver.cpp:**

```
#include "scheduler_driver.hpp"

enum task_nodes
  {
    task_0,
    task_1,
    task_2,
    task_3,
    task_4,
    task_5,
    task_6,
    task_7,
    task_8,
    task_9,
    N
  };

int basic_task(int a, int d)
{
  std::chrono::milliseconds sleepDuration(d);
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(sleepDuration);
  std::cout << "Result: " << a << "\n";
  return a;
}

using namespace SCHEDULER;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  typedef int R;
  typedef std::function<R()> F;

  Graph deps(N);
  boost::add_edge(task_0, task_1, deps);
  boost::add_edge(task_0, task_2, deps);
  boost::add_edge(task_0, task_3, deps);
  boost::add_edge(task_1, task_4, deps);
  boost::add_edge(task_1, task_5, deps);
  boost::add_edge(task_1, task_6, deps);
  boost::add_edge(task_2, task_7, deps);
  boost::add_edge(task_2, task_8, deps);
  boost::add_edge(task_2, task_9, deps);

  std::vector<F> tasks = 
    {
      std::bind(basic_task, 0, 1000),
      std::bind(basic_task, 1, 1000),
      std::bind(basic_task, 2, 1000),
      std::bind(basic_task, 3, 1000),
      std::bind(basic_task, 4, 1000),
      std::bind(basic_task, 5, 1000),
      std::bind(basic_task, 6, 1000),
      std::bind(basic_task, 7, 1000),
      std::bind(basic_task, 8, 1000),
      std::bind(basic_task, 9, 1000)
    };

  scheduler<R> *s = new scheduler<R>(std::move(deps), std::move(tasks));
  s->doit();

  return 0;
}
```

**scheduler.h:**

```
#ifndef __SCHEDULER2_H__
#define __SCHEDULER2_H__

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/visitors.hpp>

using namespace boost;

namespace SCHEDULER
{

  using Graph = adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS>;
  using Edge = graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor;
  using Vertex = graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor;
  using VectexCont = std::vector<Vertex>;
  using outIt = graph_traits<Graph>::out_edge_iterator;
  using inIt = graph_traits<Graph>::in_edge_iterator;

  template<typename R>
    class scheduler
    {
    public:
      using ret_type = R;
      using fun_type = std::function<R()>;
      using prom_type = std::promise<ret_type>;
      using fut_type = std::shared_future<ret_type>;

      scheduler() = default;
      scheduler(const Graph &deps_, const std::vector<fun_type> &tasks_) :
        g(deps_),
        tasks(tasks_) { init_();}
        scheduler(Graph&& deps_, std::vector<fun_type>&& tasks_) :
          g(std::move(deps_)),
          tasks(std::move(tasks_)) { init_(); }
        scheduler(const scheduler&) = delete;
        scheduler& operator=(const scheduler&) = delete;

        void doit();

    private:
        void init_();
        std::list<Vertex> get_sources(const Vertex& v);
        auto task_thread(fun_type&& f, int i);

        Graph g;
        std::vector<fun_type> tasks;
        std::vector<prom_type> prom;
        std::vector<fut_type> fut;
        std::vector<std::thread> th;
        std::vector<std::list<Vertex>> sources;

    };

  template<typename R>
    void
    scheduler<R>::init_()
    {
      int num_tasks = tasks.size();

      prom.resize(num_tasks);
      fut.resize(num_tasks);

      // Get the futures
      for(size_t i=0;
          i<num_tasks;
          ++i)
        {
          fut[i] = prom[i].get_future();
        }

      // Predetermine in_edges for faster traversal
      sources.resize(num_tasks);
      for(size_t i=0;
          i<num_tasks;
          ++i)
        {
          sources[i] = get_sources(i);
        }
    }

  template<typename R>
    std::list<Vertex>
    scheduler<R>::get_sources(const Vertex& v)
    {
      std::list<Vertex> r;
      Vertex v1;
      inIt j, j_end;
      boost::tie(j,j_end) = in_edges(v, g);
      for(;j != j_end;++j)
        {
          v1 = source(*j, g);
          r.push_back(v1);
        }
      return r;
    }

  template<typename R>
    auto
    scheduler<R>::task_thread(fun_type&& f, int i)
    {
      auto j_beg = sources[i].begin(), 
        j_end = sources[i].end();
      for(;
          j_beg != j_end;
          ++j_beg)
        {
          R val = fut[*j_beg].get();
        }

      return std::thread([this](fun_type f, int i)
                         {
                           prom[i].set_value(f());
                         },f,i);
    }

  template<typename R>
    void
    scheduler<R>::doit()
    {
      size_t num_tasks = tasks.size();
      th.resize(num_tasks);

      for(int i=0;
          i<num_tasks;
          ++i)
        {
          th[i] = task_thread(std::move(tasks[i]), i);
        }
      for_each(th.begin(), th.end(), mem_fn(&std::thread::join));
    }

} // namespace SCHEDULER

#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Be careful with signed and unsigned

In the `doit` routine and various others, the code compares an `int i` to a `size_t num_tasks`, but `size_t` is unsigned and `int` is signed.  Instead, declare both variables as `size_t` types.  Also, see the next suggestion.

### Be careful with namespace assumptions

The C++ standard says that `size_t` is defined in the `std` namespace.  It *might* also be defined as `::size_t` (and often is) but it's not guaranteed.  Better would be to use `std::size_t` explicitly.

### Avoid `using namespace` in headers

The `scheduler.h` header includes this line:

```
using namespace boost;
```

This may seem convenient, but it means that any code that includes this header has now brought everything from the `boost` namespace into the global namespace which is a recipe for annoying name clashes later.  If, for example, we used both your header and code like this:

```
#include "scheduler_driver.hpp"
#include <array>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
void clash() {
    using namespace std;
    array<array<int, 5>, 5> m;
}
```

it would fail to compile because of the name clash on `array`.  In this artificial example, it's easy to spot, but in real code it's a headache that will have a future programmer cursing your name.  It's easy to fix -- just remove that line and add the `boost::` namespace prefix explicitly where needed.

### Avoid data races

The `basic_task` function accesses `std::cout` but that's a single resource that might simultaneously be used by other threads.  One fix for this is to use a `std::mutex` like this:

```
static std::mutex cout_mutex;

// wherever cout is used:
some_function() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(cout_mutex);
    std::cout << "Now we can do this safely!\n";
}
```

Note that [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) is intended to be used via RAII so that the lock is obtained when the object is created and released when it's destroyed, making it easy to avoid the bug of forgetting to unlock the mutex.

I know this is just test code, but if the actual function called within your code uses shared resources, you should apply the same technique.

### Consider exceptions

If `valid()` is not `true` when `std::future::get()` is called, the behavior is undefined.  One way that can happen is if the `future` throws an exception before the computation of the result is complete.  That's not going to happen with this toy code, but if you're going to apply this scheduler to real tasks, that should be taken into account.

### Consider an alternative representation

The graph-based mechanism you current have seems to work, but I wonder if it might not be made simpler.  In particular, one thing that comes to mind is the use of a `std::priority_queue` in which the priority is simply the depth of that node in the dependency tree.  The difference is that although it would mean that none of the leaf tasks would get executed until all of the higher priority tasks were executed, the priority queue has the benefit of constant  lookup time.  Might not be a big difference with this code, (yours is linear) but it might be worth considering if you have a very large number of tasks.

### "Don't throw away your future"

OK, that sounds like it should be fatherly advice on life, but it's actually a lot more minor than that.  Within the `task_thread()` routine, the value of the `future.get()` is assigned to `val` but never used.